# Different between safe and unsafe RPC calls

Tags: rpc, security

When running a substrate node, the CLI accepts a parameter called `rpc_methods` which accepts `Auto`, `Safe` and `Unsafe` arguments.

How can developers declare an RPC call Unsafe and how can one get the list of `RpcMethods::Unsafe` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a RPC unsafe is completely up to the developer. You need to pass the [`DenyUnsafe`](https://docs.rs/sc-rpc-api/latest/sc_rpc_api/enum.DenyUnsafe.html) type to your RPC implementation. (you get the deny unsafe passed to the [`rpc_extensions_builder`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/731667f458cee06c2ac2de6855e8359fced87333/bin/node/cli/src/service.rs#L256-L275)). Then you need to call in your RPC `self.deny_unsafe.check_if_safe()?`. That's it.

> how can one get the list of RpcMethods::Unsafe methods

That is currently not supported!

Comment: Usually dangerous rpc like `author.insert_key` or expensive rpc like `state.storage_pairs` should be marked as unsafe.  You can just search substrate code base with `deny_unsafe.check_if_safe()` to find all unsafe methods as mentioned above